# How to automatically update v-bind value in a v-for loop in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am getting data from a database which is passed as a prop to my component (using static data for demo purpose) and displaying it in a form.
If the user changes the quantity, how can the total price be updated for the changed item as well?

Edited question - How can I then submit the all the values in a form ?

Html-

```
   <div class="container-fluid">
   <form action="#">
     <ul id="list-example">
       <li v-for="item in items">
         <input type="text" :value="item.name" readonly />
         <input type="number" v-model="item.quantity" min="1" />
         <input type="number" :value="item.quantity*item.price" readonly />
       </li>
     </ul>
     <input type="button" value="Submit">   
   </form>
 </div>
```

Vue-

```
new Vue({
  el: "#list-example", 
  data: {
    items: [
      { name: "Book", quantity: 5, price: 100, total: 500 },
      { name: "Pen", quantity: 2, price: 200, total: 400 },
      { name: "Marker", quantity: 7, price: 100, total: 700 }
    ]
  }
});
```

Here is a demo of the [code](https://codepen.io/sionafernandes/pen/oNLKLGX).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace it with `v-model` because it emits an `input` event witch triggers an change

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <ul id="list-example">
     <li v-for="item in items">
       <input type="text" :value="item.name" readonly />
       <input type="number" v-model="item.quantity" min="1" />
       <input type="number" v-model="item.price" readonly />
       <input type="number" :value="item.total" readonly />
       <input type="number" :value="item.quantity*item.price" readonly />
     </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you . I tried what you have suggested. While it works on code pen, the project throws error - "'v-model' directives require the attribute value which is valid as LHS." 
So its still not working

Comment: @SionaFernandes yea. i also dont used `v-model` on the `item.quantity * item.price` field. this field should not be v-model

Comment: Yes , I had read it wrong